# Draw a surface and its normal vector

Tags: pgfplots, draw, tikz-3dplot, tikz-graphdrawing

Draw the surface and its normal vector.
I want to insert a similar image in latex, how should I draw such a schematic? 
What tools should I use to draw similar diagrams?
 It may be used frequently in differential geometry and topology.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you visited the TeX.SE website, with all the information, notices, etc.?

Comment: what you try so far? where you stuck in your effort?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Zarko I tried to draw a surface with Mathematica, but I don't know how to draw the tangent vector and the normal vector on the surface.

Comment: @King.Max Here there is a best proposal https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234094/make-parametrised-surface-graphic-with-annotated-features-using-tikz-or-pgfplots

Comment: If you have $C(u,v)$, the slope of the tangent in $u$ is given by $\frac{\partial C}{\partial u}$ and the slope of the tangent in $v$ is given by $\frac{\partial C}{\partial v}$.  The normal vector is perpendicular to both.  If you don't have $C(u,v)$, fake it with a polynomial approximation or spline.

Comment: @Sebastiano THANK YOU！

Comment: @King.Max It was my pleasure. If you like to draw your figure by hand in TikZ you can do it with this quick but not accurate editor: https://www.mathcha.io/editor For any clarification available. Good job.